# Fill in the latest used file in the current directory

Tags: zsh

I am looking for a way to quickly access the latest file/directory on the command line, preferably in ZSH.

```
ls -d *(om[1])
```

Gives me just that, and if I want to use to with a command, e.g.     less *(om[1])

This works as well.

However, it is tedious to type all the brackets, and I use this **a lot** - hence I am looking for a way to create a shortcut for this string.

I've created a function in the .zshrc-file

```
lf(){ 
ls -d *(om[1])
}
```

, which I can use like this:

```
less <$(lf)
less <`lf`
```

, but I find this still less than ideal.

```
less |lf
```

does not work.

Is there a way to quickly access the latest file without the use of "hard to type characters"? Ideally, it would just be something along the lines of

```
less LATEST
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want a zsh [global alias](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_8.html)

```
alias -g latest='*(om[1])'
less latest
```

Answer (score 21):

You could use the [`_most_recent_file (^Xm)`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fmost_005frecent_005ffile-_0028_005eXm_0029).

> _most_recent_file (^Xm)
>
> Complete the name of the most recently modified file matching the pattern on the command line (which may be blank). If given a numeric argument N, complete the Nth most recently modified file. Note the completion, if any, is always unique.
>
> -- `zshcompsys(1) BINDABLE COMMANDS`

So, we can get the most recent file with typing <kbd>CTRL-x</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>. For example:

```
% less ;# typing `CTRL-X m` here, we could get:
% less newest-file-or-directory
```

And we could specify some patterns here, so for example:

```
% less *.log ;# when I want the newest *.log:
% less newest.log
```

It is necessary to have some `autoload -Uz compinit; compinit` in the `~/.zshrc` though.

Comment: very nice solution as well - I was not aware of this. I'd consider the answers equivalent, but Glenn answered first though, so I'll accept his answer.